# bios errors/warning at startup

Tags: bios

Apologies for a short and incapable of explain message. But, since I installed Ubuntu I can see this error appearing all the time and I don't have any clue on what this is and how I can get rid of it.

Any idea?
[image: BIOS error]

Comment: Does it boot and work as expect in spite of this? If so then it isn't something to worry about. And, of course, update UEFI.

Comment: Aside from the power button that has never responded since very first installation (so a press and the power dialog to appear as Ubuntu instruction would suggest), I never had a problem. Where can I update the UEFI? I will perhaps disable the message in the grub

Comment: UEFI is the firmware that replaced BIOS more than a decade ago. Like before UEFI updates and instructions are at the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Yeah sorry, let me rephrase ... where in Ubuntu can I update it. This laptop was shipped with Windows 8 which I repartioned and never used at all.

Comment: Ideally firmware updates are OS agnostic.

Comment: Don't see any UEFI driver update for this Huawei X Mate Pro. The model says MACHD-WXX9, shipped with an Intel i5

Comment: Ok, I forgot I had left a windows partition installed, I did the update via window as it was easier, but the messages are still there. I will ignore them